# How to show "edit in access" button

Tags: office-integration, datasheet, microsoft-access

how to add the `"Edit in Access"` in the Ribbon?

Currently, the Ribbon has the following: **Export to Spreadsheet**, **View RRS Feed**, **Alert Me**. thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is not added or an option you add.  It's available from lists when your access from Internet Explorer with Office plug ins enabled.

Comment: Sorry can you tell me steps by steps where to look. I am a beginner with access web datasheet. It is a SharePoint site. Thanks.